# Losing Synergy connection to server with VPN

Tags: networking, remote-access, vpn

I'm using a Cisco client to connect to a VPN but also using Synergy (Symless) to connect to the machine. It works fine initially but will drop out after machine sleep (or sometimes seemingly randomly), then I have to restart the VPN connection. Not the end of the world, but it is irritating.

Are there any config changes I can do to Networks settings, VPN or Synergy to stop this dropping out?

Answer (score 1):

Found this which I hope will fix it.

https://blog.lan-tech.ca/2013/02/21/access-local-and-vpn-network-simultaneously/

"you just need to add the local devices to the windows routing tables so that it knows to access them when the VPN is active.
See the windows “route” command – E.G. route -p add MASK 255.0.0.0 METRIC IF

To help discover what you need to use, disconnect from your VPN, make sure you can connect to your local device, then run a “route print” show the current active routes and find your device. (generally in the IPv4 Route Table)

It will also list the ‘Metric’ to use, and at the top of the listing is the “Interface List” which lists the network interfaces on your system. You’ll need to figure out which one to use. For example, I know my system has a gigabit network adapter and in the list I see a “Intel(R) Gigabit Network Connection” – bingo – that’s it. The first column is the interface id, 49 in my case.

The “-p” option makes your configuration persistent – meaning that it will be there again next time you boot.
SO, as an example, let’s say I want a local network share at 192.168.1.43 to be accessible to my machine while connected to the VPN, so I would add the route like so:

```
route -p add 192.168.1.43 MASK 255.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 METRIC 15 IF 49
```

Now if I run route print, I see this new route in the list of persistent routes for IPv4.
I turn my VPN back on, and instead of the device ‘disappearing’ as it normally does, windows can still find it because it is in the persistent route list."